# Why does konsole ignore accessibility settings?

Tags: accessibility, konsole

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with *kubuntu-desktop* and *SDDM*, the KDE Plasma display manager.

I told accessibility to flash the window for terminal bell. (I also told it to use /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/message click, which it entirely ignored in favour of ubuntu/stereo/bell, but I'm not too bothered about that right now. RIP stupid bell file, even if I had to reboot to clear some stupid cache.)

The accessibility flash works in various consoles I've tried: xterm, Eterm, rxvt, and even in Intellij and (bizarrely) gnome-terminal, yet when I use Konsole - KDE's own terminal - it does precisely nothing.

I know I can mess with xcalib and Konsole's notifications menu to tell it to flash all attached screens, but that's really not the point: shouldn't Konsole be something of a poster-boy - a well-behaved KDE application?

Update:

I make the beep by pressing backspace at an empty terminal prompt.

Comment: By "Kubuntu - Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS" do you mean "Kubuntu 18.04.3 LTS" or is this Ubuntu with kubuntu-desktop added? And how do you make the terminal bell sound? I'd like to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'm pretty sure it was Ubuntu with kubuntu-desktop added - /etc/issue says 'Ubuntu' and I recall changing the main login/display manager. I make the terminal bell by pressing `backspace` in a fresh terminal.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I searched for a terminal bell setting in konsole's settings but didn't find anything related. But please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371019/does-konsole-support-a-visible-bell.

Comment: The closest I found to terminal bell in Konsole was under Menu>Settings>Configure Notifications>Bell in visible settings, but 'play a sound' didn't work - and even if it had, someone shouldn't have to configure Konsole in addition to the accessibilty setting. I already looked at that link - it flashes the entire screen, not just the window, which is a bit overwhelming!

Comment: So just to be clear, you are logging into a Plasma session or are you using konsole in a Ubuntu (GNOME) session?

Comment: Okay, in an actual Kubuntu 18.04, I can get Konsole to emit a sound when I press backspace at the beginning of a command line prompt following your instructions.

Comment: I chanaged display manager to the KDE one, with the tartan-looking backdrop, and it comes up with a couple of dots and a chevron when it's starting. And it's not so much the sound I'm bothered about as such: it's that Konsole doesn't flash the window according to the accessibility instructions. Sound is more of a 'nice to have' for me. (I'd switch to Gnome-terminal, but it has a bright white menu bar and scroll bar I can't get rid of that messes up my vision for the top line. I prefer xterm, but it doesn't have copy/paste to clipboard, only to primary selection)